# Ruby - Regular expression to match a range like 0;60s or 0;60m

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm writing a simple command line tool and I need to match an user input in the following format:

0;60s (from 0 to 60 seconds)

0;60m (from 0 to 60 minutes)

So, I need to make sure that:

- first number must be between 0 and 60
- second number must be between 0 and 60 as well
- must have ";" between the range
- must finish with "s" or "m"
- second number must be > than the first one

What's the best approach for that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: just fixing what I wrote before: 
**second number must be > than the first one**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One regular expression that will work is the following

```
/(\d{1,2})(s|m)/
```

It will match anything 1 or 2 digits and followed by 's' or 'm' and you'll have the results stored in `$1` and `$2` respectively. To assure the first is between 0 and 60 you'll probably have to do check that `0 <= $1.to_i <= 60`.

As for the second part if you want it with the ; where you can have the range `[0-60];[0-60](s|m)` then you simply modify the regular expression to do

```
/(\d{1,2});(\d{1,2})(s|m)/
```

Then you can check `0 <= $2.to_i <= $1.to_i <= 60` and `['s', 'm'].member? $3`.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the basic pattern from the semantics. That is, I would check for "digits-semicolon-digits-s/m" with a regex. And then I'd make sure that the numbers are in the desired ranges programmatically.

This might not be the best way to do it in Ruby but this is the basic idea:

```
input =~ /^(\d+);(\d+)[sm]$/

# make sure that 0 <= Integer($1, 10) < Integer($2, 10) <= 60
```

After the first line, `$1` and `$2` contain what was found inside the first and second set of parentheses, respectively.

Checking for the `[0,60]` range within the regex, is possible too, but will get unnecessarily ugly. You'd replace `\d+` with `[0-5]?[0-9]|60`.